# Communicating timezone info across sites?

Tags: php, timezone

is there a standardized way of sending acorss timezone info of users to other sites?

What is this timezone 'format' called?
http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

```
America/Adak    America/Anchorage   America/Anguilla    America/Antigua     America/Araguaina
America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires  America/Argentina/Catamarca     America/Argentina/ComodRivadavia    America/Argentina/Cordoba   America/Argentina/Jujuy
America/Argentina/La_Rioja  America/Argentina/Mendoza   America/Argentina/Rio_Gallegos  America/Argentina/Salta     America/Argentina/San_Juan
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The timezone names are specified in the "tz database". See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zoneinfo)

Comment: yup - used that as it is... was trying to get to its "name"